# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (Probably missing brace)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm on this bug since 2 days, and my eyes can't find the glitch ... I think I've missed a brace somewhere, I did some test but none is concluant. I hope you have better eyes than me to find the glitch ...

Here is the script. I've used jQuery for making some animations with some block and adapt the height of page. Nothing special !

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function () {
    var m = 0;
    var ss = 0;
    var w = jq(window).width();
    var h = jq(window).height();
    jq("#blShuffleSong").css("width", w + 'px');
    jq("#blMG").css("width", w + 'px');
    jq("#blProject").css("width", w * 2 + 'px');
    var cd = 0;
    if (h < 585) {
        h = 585;
    } // Anti-Bleuark

    jq("#showMG").click(function () {
        if (ss == 1 && cd == 0) {
            shuffleSongtoMG();
        } else if (m == 0 && cd == 0) {
            showMG();
        } else if (m == 1 && cd == 0) {
            hideMG();
        };
    })

    jq("#showShuffleSong").click(function () {
        if (ss == 1 && cd == 0) {
            hideShuffleSong();
        } else if (m == 1 && cd == 0) {
            misterGladtoShuffleSong();
        } else if (m == 0 && cd == 0) {
            showShuffleSong();
        };
    })

    jq("#showMG").click(function () {
        if (m == 0 && cd == 0) {
            jq("#LEFTPRO").css("left", w + 'px');
            jq("#LEFTPRO").animate({
                left: '10px'
            }, 800, 'easeInOutQuint');
        }
    });

    //        jq(".linkFrancais").click(function(){
    //            hmove = h * 0.60;
    //            jq("#Home").animate({marginTop: hmove+'px'}, 500);
    //        });

    function showMG() {
        m = 1;
        cd = 1;
        jq("#INEEDTOSEEMOARPROJECTDAWG").animate({
            height: h + 'px'
        }, 300);
        jq("#blProject").css("marginLeft", w + 'px');
        jq("#blockMG").css("display", "block");
        jq("#blProject").css("display", "block");
        jq("#blProject").animate({
            marginLeft: '0px'
        }, 700, 'easeInOutQuint');
        next(1000);
    }

    function showShuffleSong() {
        ss = 1;
        cd = 1;
        jq("#INEEDTOSEEMOARPROJECTDAWG").animate({
            height: h + 'px'
        }, 300);
        jq("#blProject").css("marginLeft", w + 'px');
        jq("#blockShuffleSong").css("display", "block");
        jq("#blockMG").css("display", "block");
        jq("#blProject").css("display", "block");
        jq("#blProject").animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + w + 'px'
        }, 700, 'easeInOutQuint');
        next(1000);
    }

    function misterGladtoShuffleSong() {
        m = 0;
        ss = 1;
        cd = 1;
        jq("#blockShuffleSong").css("display", "block");
        jq("#blProject").animate({
            marginLeft: w + 'px'
        }, 700, 'easeInOutQuint', function () {
            jq("#blockMG").css("display", "block");
        });
        next(700);
    }

//Braces won't be closed at this point

    function shuffleSongtoMG() {
        ss = 0;
        m = 1;
        cd = 1;
        jq("#blockMG").css("display", "block");
        jq("#blProject").animate({
            marginLeft: '0px'
        }, 700, 'easeInOutQuint', function () {
            jq("#blockShuffleSong").css("display", "none");
        });
        next(700);
    }

    function hideMG() {
        m = 0;
        cd = 1;
        jq("#blProject").animate({
            marginLeft: w + 'px'
        }, 700, 'easeInOutQuint', function () {
            jq("#blockMG").css("display", "none");
            jq("#blProject").css("display", "none");
            jq("#INEEDTOSEEMOARPROJECTDAWG").animate({
                height: '315px'
            }, 300);
        });
        next(1000);
    }

    function hideShuffleSong() {
        ss = 0;
        cd = 1;
        jq("#blockMG").css("display", "block");
        jq("#blProject").animate({
            marginLeft: w + 'px'
        }, 1400, 'easeInOutQuint', function () {
            jq("#blProject").css("display", "none");
            jq("#blockShuffleSong").css("display", "none");
            jq("#blockMG").css("display", "none");
            jq("#INEEDTOSEEMOARPROJECTDAWG").animate({
                height: '315px'
            }, 300);
        });
        next(1700);
    }

    function next(t) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            cd = 0
        }, t);
    }

    function getSize(c) {
        var w = jq(window).width();
        var h = jq(window).height();
        var hp = 0;
        var wp = 0;
        if (h < 500) {
            hp = 500 + 'px'
        } else {
            hp = h + 'px';
        }
        jq("#LEFIRSTPAGE").css("height", hp);
        if (w < 990) {
            wp = 990 + 'px'
        } else {
            wp = w + 'px';
        }
        jq("#LEFIRSTPAGE").css("width", wp);
        if (c == 1) {
            jq("#topContainer").css("height", h * 0.40);
        };
        hbc = h * 0.60;
        hbc = hbc - 140;
        hbc = hbc / 2;
        if (c == 1) {
            jq("#bottomContainer").css("padding", hbc + 'px 0px');
        };
    }
}
```

All animation function worked before I've add the latest feature who consist to adapt the height of some blocks.

Thanks for anybody who want to help me (and for the others who took the time to read this)

Comment: http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: try to always add a semicolon at the end of each statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `);` at the end of your script:

```
jq(document).ready(function () {
...
});
```

Hope this helps!